# What is the origin of the error "cannot move out of borrowed content"?

Tags: rust

I've never understood why I have received the Rust error "cannot move out of borrowed content".

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::vec::Vec;

pub struct user_type {
    pub name: String,
    pub ilist: Vec<i32>,
    pub user_type_list: VecDeque<Option<Rc<RefCell<user_type>>>>,
    pub parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<user_type>>>,
}

impl user_type {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        user_type {
            name: name.clone(),
            ilist: Vec::new(),
            user_type_list: VecDeque::new(),
            parent: Option::None,
        }
    }

    pub fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut result: String = String::new();

        result += "name is ";
        result += &self.name;

        let n = self.user_type_list.len();

        for iter in &self.user_type_list {
            match iter {
                Some(ref x) => {
                    let temp = x.into_inner();
                    let temp2 = temp.to_string();
                    result += &temp2[..];
                }
                None => panic!("to_string"),
            }
            result += "\n";
        }

        result
    }
}
```

The full error message is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:34:32
   |
34 |                     let temp = x.into_inner();
   |                                ^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

What is the origin of this kind of error?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `UserType` instead, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully at this code:

```
for iter in &self.user_type_list {
    match iter {
        Some(ref x) => {
            let temp = x.into_inner();
            let temp2 = temp.to_string();
            result += &temp2[..];
        }
        None => panic!("to_string"),
    }
    result += "\n";
}
```

Here, you are iterating `&self.user_type_list` so the type of `iter` is actually a reference to the contained value: `&Option<Rc<RefCell<user_type>>>`. That is nice, because you do not want to take ownership of the container or its values.

Then you match `iter` to `Some(ref x)`. Older compiler versions would fail because you are matching a reference to a non-reference, but new compilers will do as if you are matching a `Option<&T>` instead of a `&Option<T>`, if needed. That is handy, and means that you can write just `Some(x) =>` and `x` will be of type `&Rc<RefCell<user_type>>` instead of `&&Rc<..>` (not that it really matters, automatic dereferencing will make those equivalent).

Now you are calling `x.into_inner()` with a `&Rc<RefCell<..>>` and that will never work. It looks like you want to get the `RefCell` into `temp` that is not needed, `Rc` implements `Deref` so you get that for free. Instead the compiler thinks you are calling `RefCell::into_inner(self) -> T`, but this function consumes the `self` to get to the contained value. And you do not own it, you just borrowed it. That is what the error message means: you are trying to consume (move out) and object you do not own (borrowd).

What you really want is just to borrow the `user_type` enough to call `to_string()`:

```
Some(x) => { 
    let temp = x.borrow().to_string();
    result += &temp;
}
```